# Lamp socket question

Tags: lamp, socket

[image]

What are the endings at the end of the wires of this light bulb socket called? I can't seem to find any like this online.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

They are just called "push-on" single pin crimp-on connectors. There are different types of push-on connectors, these are referred to as "bullet" type. You can usually find them where they sell ring and fork tongue connectors.

[image: Example of crimp connector styles]

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell but they looks like a single pin Molex connector based on the pin and plastic sleeve one male and 1 female so the polarity can not be reversed if the fixture you are installing this in only has bare wires you can cut these ends off and wire nut them. Make sure the black wire goes to the hot (this should be the center contact) and the neutral / white goes to the shell or threaded part.